# Rails not routing to the correctly as defined in routes.rb in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

If index page is present in the public directory it will open the `index.html` page in the browser when I enter the URL.

If I delete the `index.html` file from the public directory it will show me the localhost Apache page.

But according to the routing it should show me `index.html.erb` inside the home controller.

I have the virtual host set up like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName rapp.dev

      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/public

      <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
           AllowOverride All
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My routing in `routing.rb` file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources 'home'
  get 'home/index'
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: How are you running your rails server? Do you user Passenger? Unicorn? Puma? It seems like your app is not really behind any server like that. Apache by itself does not know how to handle Rails application
Read more below:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/fundamental_concepts.html
http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/02/10/which-ruby-app-server-is-right-for-you

Comment: installed the passenger module of Apache to run the rails application on it.
The application is running fine via rails s command on localhost:3000

Comment: can you access any other routes through the application? Like devise? Have you restarted apache server after installing apache?
Try running ```passenger-status``` command on the server and see what the output is

Comment: o/p: ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service.

Comment: OK, so it seems like passenger is not installed/enabled correctly. Please follow instructions at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/install_language_runtime.html and you should have it up and running without any issues